# Ошибка 500 без логов

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-500

Перенес проект с хостинга на VPS. Начала появляться ошибка 500

**А теперь самое главное:**

Отключен показ ошибок - Ошибка 500

Включен показ ошибок: Белый экран

Логирование включено, но в логах ничего нет.

Как такое возможно, что ошибка есть, а информации о ней нет?

Comment: Не настроены логи должным образом

Comment: @ArchDemon все настроено. Я вам говорю что даже показ ошибок включаешь и ничего не отображается

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file